# Non-Modal view without NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, non-modal

I have an app built from the UITabBarController starter project.  The first tab is part of the main.xib that contains the tab bar.  I would like to slide a view up from the bottom on top of that tab's view that only covers part of the screen.  My understanding is that you can only cover part of the screen if you make the top view non-modal, but I don't see a way to do that without a NavigationController.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

you can add a UIView as a subview to the current view, and then animate its appearance into the screen using animation blocks, or Quartz or however you would like.

Answer (score 0):

`presentModalViewController:` is actually a method that belongs to `UIViewController`, the superclass of `UINavigationController`, so you can use it from *any* view controller, not just a navigation controller.

Comment: i think he only wants the view to be a partial fill of the screen, which is not possible with a modal view prior to 3.2.

Comment: That's true.  How do you do it in 3.2 or higher?

Comment: there are a few different UIModalPresentationStyles that can be used on iPad specifically.  However they still dim the rest of the screen not in use by the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  That's an easy way to get a view with a few buttons for user input to slide up and only cover the bottom portion of the current view.